# Multiplication by a constant in a definite integral

Tags: integration

If I'm not mistaken, if $k$ is some constant, $f(x)$ is some real-valued function and $a$ and $b$ $\in \mathbb{R}$  then $\int^b_a k f(x) dx = k \int^b_a f(x) dx$.

Now, if I know $\int^b_a k f(x) dx= k \int^b_a f(x) dx$ does that mean $k$ is a constant? It feels like it should but it also feels like a strong statement. Any counter-examples or proof?

Comment: These look like *indefinite* integrals to me (no limits of integration), not definite integrals.  If you're talking about definite integrals, your proposition is false.  $\int_{x=-1}^1 (2x+2)x^2 \, dx = 2\int_{x=-1}^1 x^2 \, dx$, but $2x+2$ is not a constant.

Comment: Forgot the limits, sorry, will edit. Thanks for the answer Brian Tung.

Comment: Actually, I do not think your answer is right Brian Tung. (2x+2) is different from 2.

Comment: Brian those two integrals are the same because the function you added evaluated to 0, and a constant times zero is still zero, this still supports the case that pulling out multiplicative constants works

Comment: If you do mean definite integrals, then what does it mean to pull out $k$ outside the integral, if $k$ is not a constant?  What do you expect $k$ looks like?

Comment: It can be proven from the limit definition that this property of the definite integral is true, otherwise it wouldnt be listed under properties of definite integrals

Comment: @Dan: I'm trying to probe what he means exactly.  Of course, pulling out a constant works, but that doesn't sound like what he's asking.  He's asking the converse: If you pull something out, and it's still "correct," does that mean $k$ is a constant.  I'm asking, what does it even mean to pull out $k$ if it *isn't* a constant?

Comment: To elaborate: Once you compute the definite integral $\int_{x=a}^b f(x) \, dx$, you no longer have a function of $x$; you have a function of $a$ and $b$, ostensibly, but not a function of $x$.  So then, if $k$ isn't a constant, what is it a function of?

Comment: It can be a function of any variable that isn't the independent variable under consideration, this is true for multiple integrals too (so long as the integration limits do not depend on further variables, ie are constant compared to all the variables)

Comment: If that's the case, it seems to me that it could be anything, so long as $x$ doesn't depend on it.  For instance, $k$ could be $2c+d$, and you could pull it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\int_a^b f(x) \neq 0$ then $k$ must be constant, since $k(x) = \frac{\int_a^b kf(y)\,dy}{\int_a^b f(y)\,dy}$ clearly does not depend on $x$.

If $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = 0$ then the equation holds if $\int_a^b k(x)f(x)\,dx$ also vanishes. An easy such example (with $a\neq b$) is $f(x) = x$, $k(x) = x^2$, $a=-1$, $b=1$.